# If you delete a post with downvotes, will you get your reputation back?

Tags: discussion, reputation

What happens when someone downvotes your post and you delete the post? Will you get your reputation back? I have been losing a lot of reputation (from 17 to 9) and lost privileges.

Comment: Please don't add "Solved" to your questions. Accepting answer to a question is indication that you have appropriate solution. See: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: You should avoid submitting a contribution and then deleting it due to downvotes. All contributions are considered once they are submitted in the determination if you are or are not able to submit additional contributions without a rate limit.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you will get back any reputation lost from downvotes on that post when you delete a post. (You will also lose any reputation gained from upvotes on that post. From a reputation perspective, it will be as if that post never existed.)

*However*, you need to be very careful when deleting questions, as you could easily end up with a [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). As a relatively new user (having contributed very little content), the system has less "trust" for the quality of content you generate. If you post multiple questions that get downvotes, and then you delete them rather than improving them, you'll end up losing the privilege of asking questions. I'm sure you don't want that, so I strongly recommend against deleting questions you've asked simply because they've received downvotes. (Note that as it says in the linked FAQ, moderators don't control the question bans; these are automatic. We can give you advice on how to avoid them and how to get out of them, but we can't lift them, no matter how nicely you ask.)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm not a new user I don't know why It says that. On stack overflow it says I'm not a new user and also in communities my only community is stack overflow and when I log in with google it asks me to create a new account

Comment: It says you're a new user here on Meta, which you are; you haven't been on Meta very long. However, that's not what I'm referring to in my answer when I say that you're "a relatively new user". The length of time which you've had an account (~9 months) doesn't matter. What matters are your contributions. Your oldest post (a question) is from January 30th, and you've only got a total of 4 questions (including one deleted question). That doesn't give very much signal to the quality-control system, and especially if you start deleting downvoted questions, you'll be getting *very* close to a block